# Nested Forms in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have several tables linking our business' computers with the software that they have.

- [Computers] shows the data for each computer as far as hardware
- [Programs] lists all the programs we own
- [Software Type] types of software for programs in [Programs]
- [Program Demand] links each computer to each program for a many-to-many- relationship

I want to create a nested form that shows each computer and then lists all the software by software type.

1. Computer Name

   - Software type 1

     - Program 1
     - Program 2
     - Program 3
   - Software type 2

     - Program 1
     - Program 2
     - Program 3

I've tried several times with the wizard and tried creating the forms individually and then dragging them into the main form. I guess I'm unsure of what to include on each individual form to get them to link properly. How do I do this correctly? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Do you need this in a form so you can edit it?  Because to just show it, it would be SUPER easy to do in a report.

Comment: Yes I'm going to format it so a user can look at and click check boxes if it has the software or not. It would be so much easier if I just had to report cause then I could use the grouping and sorting.

Comment: I have the form almost how I want it but access won't let me show the second tier as a continuous form. Is there a way around this, or did I set it up wrong yet again?

Comment: I've honestly never done anything like that, but it would seem like putting a subform on a form, and then using that form as a subform on another form should be pretty straight-forward and give you what you need.  You would just need to make sure the Parent/Child keys make sense.  I'm assuming each table has some Primary Key?

Comment: Yes, each table has a primary key, and all tables are linked with one to many relationships. I have a form set up now that is single form for each computer and then lists software type-program in a subform. It would just be more visually appealing to the user if the software types were grouped together. I can nest the forms but access allows only single-form format. Is there another way to group in a form other than using subforms?

Comment: Have you considered using a TreeView?  They're kind of a bear to set up, but I've done it before and gotten some cool results.  Then you can make each node clickable, so that you can open an edit form with the info from whatever node you've selected.

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for, I have gotten my form to look like that, however I'm looking for more of a continuous form for the programs, grouped by program type. At this point I am settling with the main form showing the computer and one sub-form showing all the information. I am just sorting by program type and then program name. It's not perfect but functional. Any more comments are appreciated, but thank everyone so far for your input.